# Is JMX collected system data just for the runner process or the whole OS all processes?

Tags: cpu, jmx

I am studying JMX. By comparing the following output, and `top` output, is JMX memory, sysload and cpu time data for the whole OS or just the runner process?
By calculating change rate of two samples, one can get used cpu percentage.

```
OperatingSystemMXBean mxBean =  ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
long prevUpTime = runtimeMXBean.getUptime() * 1000000;
long prevProcessCpuTime = mxBean.getProcessCpuTime();
```

By calculating used memory again available memory, one can get used memory percentage.

```
        MemoryMXBean memoryMXBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
        long total = 0L;
        long max = memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax();
        long used = memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();
        long committed = memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getCommitted();
        if (max != -1) {
            total = Math.min(max, committed);
        }
        return (double) used / total;
```